# IE9 slow rendering while using IIS 7.5 (but not with file protocol)

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer-9, iis-7.5

i'm currently having a weird problem with ie9, (32bits)
i'm trying to display a page (with lot of tables, images, css and js)

when i display the page using the http protocol the page takes about 4sec to render/display
now if i try to display the exact same page using the file protocol (file://) the page is displayed in less than a second
i also tried chrome browser which display the page in both protocols in less than a second

i'm using iis 7.5 as a local webserver

i've timed those using the network option in developper tool of ie9 (f12)

here is a screenshot of what it shows when using http:

[image]
[image]

i'm wondering why it takes so long for the page to be ready

thanks in advance ;)

Comment: Anti-virus from ESET by any chance?

Comment: Disable the AV and test with other browsers for performance, especially a useful test is telnetting to port 80 and issuing a manual request.

Comment: Disabling the AV is not changing much, other browser behave mostly like Chrome (less than a sec), IE8 is a bit faster than IE9 (3sec), tlenetting port 80 didnt show me much, the response arrive very quickly all the headers seems correct ...